# How to publish wcf service library which is referenced in asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

1. I referenced the Wcf service library project to my ASP.NET Web application's Service references.
2. I published the Web application alone in Local IIS server. But  FinananceService.svc service file didnt add in the publiashed folder after publishing. So I manually pasted FinananceService.svc file in published folder. Hence I able to browse the FinananceService.svc file using "http://localhost:8080/FinanceService.svc"
   3.But when I run the application, Wcf service is not getting called from asp.net web pages.

**Web.config file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <system.web>
     <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="360"></sessionState>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlConn" connectionString="Data Source=HASHBYTESSERVER;Initial Catalog=Swasthik;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=hasH35" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Swas/FinanceService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFinanceService1" contract="HashFinanceService.IFinanceService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFinanceService"/>
    </client>
<services>
<service name="HashFinanceService.FinanceService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" >
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/FinanceService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFinanceService"
contract="HashFinanceService.IFinanceService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IFinanceService" listenUri="/">                
</endpoint>
<host>
<baseAddresses >
<add  baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/"/>
</baseAddresses>
</host>
</service>
</services>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFinanceService" closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
</binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFinanceService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomWSBindingTcp">
          <reliableSession enabled="true"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
<behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true "/>
              </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
          </behaviors>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="Login.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**Published folder structure:**

[image: Published folder structure]

Please guide me how to handle this.

Comment: Please post some code and share the error message you are getting. I'd debug the place where the asp.net web application is  attempting to call the WCF Service.

Comment: I modified My question. Please check it once